# How to set cache control headers in a Django view class (no-cache)

Tags: django, caching, django-views, browser-cache

Now this took me some time to figure out, so I will self-answer it.
I wanted to disable browser caching for one specific page in Django on a View. There is some information how to do this if the view is a function, but not if it's a class.
I did not want to use a middleware, because there was only one specific view that I didn't want to be cached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are decorators to do this, for example `cache_control` and `never_cache` in `django.views.decorators.cache`

For a function, you would just decorate the function like this

```
@never_cache
def my_view1(request):
    # your view code

@cache_control(max_age=3600)
def my_view2(request):
    # your view code
```

see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers

Now, if your view is a class, you have to apply another method, that I already knew of for using authentication, but did not make the connection. There is another decorator for the class to decorate functions within the class

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

decorators = [never_cache,]

@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class MyUncachedView(FormView):
    # your view code
```

This will decorate the form method `dispatch` with the decorators specified in the `decorators` list, defined above. You don't have to implement the dispatch method, btw.

There are also other variations to do that, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class