# My "cart" cookie in the request passed to my Django view is empty despite it showing in browser storage

Tags: django, cookies, django-views, passenger

I have a store page on my site (written in Django w/ a Passenger server) where users can add products to their shopping cart. The cart is stored as a cookie. When they proceed from the store page to the cart page, the cart view should list all of the items in their cart (which it gets from the cart cookie in the request). This works fine when I run it locally. However, when I run this in production, it almost always says the cart is empty. It only lists the cart items properly if I do a hard refresh of the page.

I've added some print statements to the server, and I can see that the view for the page is being called twice in prod (it's only called once in dev). The first time the view is called, the cart cookie has the correct values. The second time it's called however, the cart cookie in the request is an empty object {}. All other cookies in the request look normal (session id, csrftoken, etc). What's very strange is I can see in the browser's developer panel that the cart cookie is populated in both the request's header cookie tab as well as the storage tab.

Django view/utility functions:

```
def cart_view(request):
    data = cart_data(request)

    context = {
        'items': data['items'],
        'order': data['order'],
        'cart_items': data['cart_items'],
    }

    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def cart_cookie(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}
    return cart

def cart_data(request):
    cart = cart_cookie(request)
    items = []
    order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0, 'shipping': False}
    cart_items = order['get_cart_items']
    '''
    Logic to parse the cart cookie
    '''     
    return {
        'items': items,
        'order': order,
        'cart_items': cart_items,
    }
```

Here's the functions on the store page to populate the cart:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart');

for (var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var productId = this.dataset.product;
        var action = this.dataset.action;
        updateCartCookie(productId, action);
    })
}

function updateCartCookie(productId, action) {
    if (action == 'add') {
        if (cart[productId] === undefined) {
            cart[productId] = {'quantity':0};
        }
        cart[productId]['quantity'] += 1;
    } else if (action == 'remove') {
        cart[productId]['quantity'] -= 1;
        if (cart[productId]['quantity'] <= 0) {
            delete cart[productId];
        }
    }
    document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/;SameSite=Strict;Secure;";
    location.reload();
}
```

This code is in the page header to initialize the cookies. It's not being called on navigation to the cart page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1))
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); // this is just a string
    var cart = JSON.parse(getCookie('cart')); // this is a json object, so we need to parse it

    if (cart == undefined) {
        cart = {};
        document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/;SameSite=Strict;Secure;";
    }
</script>
```

And finally, here are the templates for the Store and Cart pages
#Store

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title">Store</h1>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}">
            <br>
            <div class="box-element product">
                <div>
                    <h4><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h4>
                    <hr>
                    <p>
                        {{product.description}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                    <h4>{{ product.price|floatformat:-2 }}</h4>
                    <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn light update-cart">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div>
        <a style="float: right; margin: 5px;" class="btn dark" href="{% url 'cart' %}">Cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

#Cart

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title">Cart</h1>
    <div class="">
        <a class="btn button light" href="{% url 'store' %}">&#x2190; Store</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        {% if cart_items == 0 %}
            <p style="text-align: center;">Your cart is empty.</p>
        {% else %}
        <div>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <div class="shrinking-flex-column-2-1"><strong>Item</strong></div>
                <div class="static-flex-column-1"><strong>Price</strong></div>
                <div class="static-flex-column-1"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
                <div class="static-flex-column-1"><strong>Total</strong></div>
            </div>
            {% for item in items %}
            <div class="cart-row" style="align-items: center;">
                <div class="shrinking-flex-column-2-1">{{item.product.name}}</div>
                <div class="static-flex-column-1">${{item.product.price}}</div>
                <div class="static-flex-column-1">
                    <p class="quantity">x{{item.quantity}}</p>
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <img class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static 'store/images/arrow-up.png' %}" data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="add" >
                        <img class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static 'store/images/arrow-down.png' %}" data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="remove" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="static-flex-column-1">${{item.get_total}}</div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                <div>
                    <h5>Total Order Items: <strong>{{order.get_cart_items}}</strong></h5>
                    <h5>Total Order Amount: <strong>${{order.get_cart_total}}</strong></h5>
                </div>
                <a class="btn dark" role="button" href="{% url 'checkout' %}">Checkout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being entirely a caching issue. Adding the @never_cache decorated to the cart/checkout views fixed the problem.

[How to set cache control headers in a Django view class (no-cache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213723/how-to-set-cache-control-headers-in-a-django-view-class-no-cache)